# How to get text on top of image and stop image resizing?

Tags: html, css

Here's my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uh2ptg23/1/

If you expand the Results box, you'll see that each colored bar is supposed to be floating next to each other inline. My goal is to get 'Cranes' ontop of the yellow, 'Erognomic Lifting' ontop of the blue, and 'Fall Protection' on top of the green. The other issue I'm having is that when the window is resized, the colored bars overlap ontop of each other. I don't necessarily want this, I want them to stay at 100% size and to stay off of each other and floated inline.

HTML:

```
<div class="sections">
<div class="cranes">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/79SghD7.jpg" id="craneButton">
<span id="craneText">Cranes</span>
</div>
<div class="ergonomicLifting">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/3HLElPO.jpg" id="ergoButton">
<span id="ergoText">Ergonomic Lifting</span>
</div>
<div class="fallProtection">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/IOb8O3I.jpg" id="fallButton">
 <span id="fallText">Fall Protection</span>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sections {
width: 75%;
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.cranes {
float: left;
width: 33%;
position: relative;
}

.ergonomicLifting {
float: left;
width: 33%;
position: relative;
}

.fallProtection {
float: left;
width: 33%;
position: relative;
}

#craneText {
position: absolute;
z-index: 1000;
}

#fallText {
z-index: 1000;
position: absolute;
}

#ergoText {
z-index: 1000;
position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: can you use the img, as background img for the span?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/uh2ptg23/2/)

**CSS**

```
.sections {
    width: 75%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.sections div span {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.sections div {
    float: left;
    width:33%;
    position: relative;
}

.sections div img {
    max-width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `<span>` tags should be before the `<img>` tags.